# How to caching images with Glide?

Tags: android, caching

I use *Glide* to load images (from drawables) to *ImageButtons*, but sometimes the images doesn't appears, and I get *E/libEGL: cache file failed CRC check* error by the logcat. So my question is, how can I caching these images?

My code:

.xml:

```
          <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/home_ib1_24_hours_to_live"
            android:layout_width="98dp"
            android:layout_height="155dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

.java:

```
    home_ib1_24_hours_to_live = 
    (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.home_ib1_24_hours_to_live);
    Glide.with(Home.this)
            .load(R.drawable.moviep_24_hours_to_live)
            .centerCrop()
            .fitCenter()
            .into(home_ib1_24_hours_to_live);
```

And I know I could load images from url, but what sites does the *Android* supports? Or, How it works?

Comment: can you read https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use glide to set a drawable ? You can just call :

```
home_ib1_24_hours_to_live.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.moviep_24_hours_to_live));
home_ib1_24_hours_to_live.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
```

Comment: And if I use that, it's not problem, that my image is in 980x1550? Because I want to use in an ImageButton, that's 98x155, and when I make this (980x1550) images in 98x155 the resolution is very pixel. But if I use a bigger image, I got an outofmemory error. That's why I tought try to use Glide. (And I want to use 50+ ImageButton in 1 Layout)

Comment: In this case , why you don't resize your drawable or image ?

Comment: Because if I make a 98x155 image, it is full of pixels.

Comment: Make it 245x388